# Convert BIOS booting to UEFI in existed linux installation

Tags: debian, boot, uefi

I have debian installed on HDD with GPT partition table. But it installed with BIOS compatible mode. Now I want to boot it from native UEFI. How can I do this?

Ofcource I have motherboard with UEFI.

Comment: I dont think that it is possible

Comment: There is an answer to this question [on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair). I wish there would be instruction specific for Debian too. Edit: indeed, someone [wrote](http://www.getreu.net/public/downloads/doc/legacy2UEFIboot/Transform-Debian_7_wheezy-from_legacy_to_UEFI_boot_mode.html) a guide for Debian 7

Comment: this is *very* easy. just repartition, uninstall `grub`, install the rEFInd package, and reboot.